# Declaring my ArrayList to get .jpg images from my database

Tags: android, database, image, arraylist

Anyone know why I am getting this error and a solution on fixing it?

My declaration:

```
ArrayList<Image> specificItemImage;  <<The error is: Image cannot be resolved to a type.
```

Here I retrieve the images from the database I am using:

```
specificItemImage = mDbHelper.getItemMultiTableData("item_master.[item_image]", "item_master", "item", "item_master.[id]", "item.[item_master_id]", "item_att", "item.[id]", "item_att.[item_id]", "item_att.[attribute_id] = 3");
```

The list of Images I am retrieving from the database is .jpg.

So my question would be, what would I have to declare my ArrayList to be to get a list of .jpg images from my database?

Comment: Are you storing the image as a BLOB or are you just storing the image filename?

Comment: @wyoskibum I am using sqlite and storing the image as a .jpg inside of there.  I thought that getting the column from the database would return an ArrayList of .jpg Images, which my logic was the above code  I hope this is what you were asking, cause this is kinda new to me retrieving a list of images from the database.  I am fimiliar with getting strings so I followed the same logic.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any experience storing images in tables.  I usually store the filename and use that to view the image resource.  Can you add a column to your table that has the filename so you can have a String Arraylist?